# SeriesMaster not being returned when getting the CalendarView using the Office 365 API

Tags: ms-office, office365, exchangewebservices

The documentation (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/howto/sync-calendar-view) for getting a calendarview implies that the `SeriesMaster` event will be returned in the result, along with the individual occurrences and exceptions.

The documentation states (and shows by example):

> Here's the information you need to know about how recurring events are handled for calendar view synchronization.
>
> - The service performs meeting expansion and sends the series master event and all of the event instances within the time window.
> - The series master event contains the recurrence pattern and the time window for the series.
> - The event instances contain their start and end time information as well as information about event occurrence exception.

However in actually using this endpoint, we're only receiving back the Occurrences/Exceptions and not the recurrence "master". The Occurences are full models, unlike slimmer models containing only the start/end like the documentation states.

It's important for us to be able to get sync SeriesMaster events along with the exceptions for the series (as is possible with GCal `singleEvents=false`) such that we can store this information and perform recurrence expansion on the client-side.

What am I doing wrong here?

Request (decoded for readability):

```
GET https://outlook.office365.com/api/v1.0/Users(...)/calendarview?$sort=startDateTime desc&$top=100&startDateTime=2016-01-01T22:12:34+0000&endDateTime=2016-03-10T23:12:34+0000
```

There is a similar issue when we try to get the CalendarView in EWS.

Answer (score 0):

The Outlook calendar sync REST API works well as the description for me. Did the API works for you when you remove the $top query parameters?

Because the Outlook calendar sync REST API doesn't support $filter, $count, $select, $skip, $top, and $search query parameters.

Here is the link for the sync API for your reference:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/office/office365/api/calendar-rest-operations#Syncevents

Here is the response from calendar sync for your reference:
[image]